# Feature or extension to save/restore form fields content?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I'm debugging the client-side scripts of a large HTML form. It will really help if I could get the fields automatically filled-out with predetermined content. Ideally, I'd like to be able to fill out with one chosen set of values from a predefined collection.

What's a good feature or extension for Firefox/Chromium for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set default values in html
or you can listener to window.onload and set it in javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/vtSen/

```
<input value="xxx" />
```

here is an example

Comment: Thanks, but I have multiple forms, each with multiple value sets I'd like to choose from. Supporting all of that amounts to writing my own, fairly involved extension, which I'd like to avoid if possible :)

Comment: i suggest you implement the function in a well defined javascript module so you can get the tool in your life. this is a generic tool you will use often. your code will not limit to a specific browser and easy to test. i think an extension is just the same code write by other people. :)